# How to generate the same short link short link with Firebase short link API if same url is provided?

Tags: firebase, firebase-dynamic-links

I'm just exploring the short link API from Firebase.

I found every time when i created a short link, unique short link is generated even i provide the same link.

Is it possible to retrieve the old link generated instead of creating new short link each time without storing the old short link on my side?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please add a [minimal working example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of your issue or the steps to reproduce the issue. There must be something changing between calls to create the link, as the same underlying long dynamic link/link definition should produce the same short link.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: @samthecodingman I just tried to create the same short link twice with the exact same underlying long dynamic link, but the created short links are different.